# UWP application shutdown after 3 days 21 hours

Tags: uwp

I developed a Monitoring system with sensors.The application must be run for 365 days, 24 hours.

Now, I am testing the applicaiton for long running. To prevent suspend , I wrote this.

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<!--<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />-->
<rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime" />
<rescap:Capability Name="extendedExecutionUnconstrained" />
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

and I added this code too.

```
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.Activated -= CoreWindow_OnActivated;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.Activated += CoreWindow_OnActivated;

private void CoreWindow_OnActivated(CoreWindow sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // This seems to be the last chance we get to enable extended execution when going to the background.
        // Trying this on OnVisibilityChanged, OnEnteredBackground, or OnSuspending is too late.
        if ((null != args) && (CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated == args.WindowActivationState))
        {
            ExtendedExecutionManager.Instance.BeginExtendedExecutionIfNeeded();
        }
    }
```

in first test, My application can run 3 days 21 hours. but Suddently, It has closed without any error, without Any event viewer log.

**Is this a limitation of UWP applicaiton ??**

the application is installed as a Sideloaded package.

**Update 1:**

When I make side load application, I checked this. but Eventviewer has no Exception record. Is there any way to know UWP application crash log ?

[image]

Update 2

I tried to test small UWP application and throw exception intentionally.
With , Without PDB file in sideload package, EventViewer catch "Applicaton Error". but My application was crashed without any message on eventViewer...

I want to say why... but No one can reply.....
Please give me more comments.

To re-build with WPF ,it's not possible,It will take anotehr 6 month !

[image]

(First Error is with PDB file in sideload. last error is without PDB )

Comment: I think creating a UWP application for monitoring purpose does not seem to be the best solution because UWP lifecycle is designed keeping in mind that user will switch b/w apps and the execution of the app needs to be paused for the time. I would suggest creating a windows service for the end target you want to achieve because for that you don't need to write any code for making it active, it will run until your system is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I finally chose below idea.

1. Download and Run it.( A free application "[Restart on Crash](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/03/04/restart-on-crash/)" )
2. Make a batch file to restart when crash.( [How to](http://www.mrlacey.com/2017/01/launch-store-installed-app-from-command.html) )
3. Using "Restart on Crash" application, Setup like this.

[image]

the batch file like this.

```
@echo off
start shell:AppsFolder\2313d654-0c37-461f-ae1e-31336dde7fb3_sasbmbdd83txa!App
```

After close UWP application, The free software immediately restart !
for me, It is enough.

Thank you, Stackoverflow users !